# How to store molecule data using SMILES when building a toy chemistry model

Tags: cheminformatics

I'm currently building a toy chemistry model based around Gillespie's algorithm. Starting from a food set of {H,O,N,C} I let my system evolve, I have been storing my molecules as strings in SMILES format.

For instance:

[O] reacts with [H] --> [O] ([H])

[O] ([H]) reacts with [H] --> [O] ([H]) ([H])

Using square brackets I've been able to keep the molecules in my system consistent with their SMILES interpretation.

However this system of storage is only allowing me to construct linear molecules.

How can I create, for instance, a carbon ring, so that it is interpreted in SMILES as only a ring of carbon atoms, without hydrogen atoms?

For instance C1CCCCC1 gives http://www.chemicalize.org/structure/#!mol=C1CCCCC1&source=calculate
How would I generate 6 carbon atoms in a ring without the 12 hydrogen?

Comment: There is no such molecule as a six-membered carbon ring without hydrogens, there have to be some substituents there. To remove the hydrogens you would have to assume triple bonds, and those are linear and you couldn't form a ring.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html) for decent documentation on the SMILES format.  SMILES can be drawn and written in both hydrogen-suppressed and hydrogen-complete formats.  Regarding @MadScientist's comment, are you trying to get your algorithm to evolve the unrealistic carbon-ring-without-hydrogens or are you more concerned with the visualization of your evolved molecules?

Comment: As you may have guessed, I almost no background in chemistry whatsoever. Why can't this molecule exist? How does this form, does a hydrocarbon fold in on itself?



@bobthechemist I'm trying to get my algorithm to be capable of evolving rings of atoms, I'm planning on adjusting the physical realism later.

Comment: @Freeman The answer to your question probably can't be contained in the 600 characters allowed for a comment, and is beyond the scope of the question you asked.  Nonetheless, I suggest looking at [this online textbook](https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/) with particular attention to chapter 9, which describes chemical bonding.  (You might need to skim chapters 2 and 3 beforehand).